# Should I use eval to patch/extend a widget?

Tags: javascript, eval

This question may be too opinion based but since avoiding `eval` is almost unanimously agreed upon, I'd imagine there should be objective answers.

I'd like to "patch" an existing open-source widget to avoid creating my own custom build of it. But the parts I want to patch are internal functions which are completely hidden. IE:

```
function dostuff(){
    function iCantBeEdittedSinceImNotAPrototypeMethod_unlessDoStuffIsCompletelyOverwrittenButItsVeryLong(){
        //code that needs patched
    };
};
```

The only way I can see of doing this is to turn the function `dostuff` into text, search and replace `iCantBeEditted` and then eval it.

How bad is this use of `eval`?

And the specific context that I'd like to use this with is fullcalendar's [`compareSegs`](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/81e436cc0be82e54940e3e26d44c1eae51cfe7b1/src/common/Grid.events.js#L415) function that decides sorts the order of events.

Concerns:

- safety of eval
- modifying a minified file. I can find the desired function with a somewhat fail safe pattern but even if I make it variable name agnostic, this could cause problems when fullcalendar is updated.
- performance. This file is 72kb after being minified.

So, should I do this? Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: If your use-case is a valid one, why not contribute a patch that makes it possible for other users to do the same thing? Or at least -- why not discuss your use-case with the project maintainer?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364 It's been planned for 3 years now. Seems to be ignored

Comment: Also, it's not just for this case. I've wanted a way to patch internal functions (like how you use plugins to extend something) for a while.

Comment: If it's an open-source project, better fork it and patch the source instead of using `eval`. If you cannot do that, using `eval` is totally ok.